# Цикл for. Почему допустимо выражение

Tags: javascript

Почему в цикле в данном случае срабатывает только функция?

Она заменяет выражение **{}** для **for**?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
!function(i){
  console.log('Один')
}(i)
console.log('Два')
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что с такой вещью, как `!function(i){...}(i)` вопросов не возникло?

Comment: @PavelMayorov я раскрыл сей вопрос )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это связано с автоматическим определением конца инструкции в JavaScript.

[Хабр: Всё, что надо знать о точке с запятой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111563/)

Если код не содержит явных указаний конца инструкции ";", то интепретатор JavaScript действует примерно по следующему правилу: если он может поставить в конце ";", то он это делает, в противном случае ищет завершение на другой строке. Поскольку for требует одной инструкции по синтаксису `for(инициализатор; условие; итератор) инструкция;`, интерпретатор не находит ее на первой строке и ищет на следующей. Функция является неделимой, поэтому он ее тоже считывает до конца и ставит конец оператора прямо после нее, закрывая цикл.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)    //тут нельзя
!function(i)  //тут нельзя
    { console.log('Один') //тут нельзя
}(i) ;//тут конец
console.log('Два');
```

В итоге получается так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) !function(i) { console.log('Один') }(i); //цикл закрыт
console.log('Два');
```

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите как определяют конструкцию `for` [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) :

> `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
>      statement`

Причём про `statement` указывается:

> A statement that is executed as long as the condition evaluates to true. To execute multiple statements within the loop, use a block statement ({ ... }) to group those statements. To execute no statement within the loop, use an empty statement (;).

*Инструкция, которая выполняется если условие соответствует инстине. Чтобы выполнять в цикле несколько инструкций, группируйте их в фигурных скобках (`{..}`). Чтобы не выполнять никаких инструкций в цикле, используйте пустую инструкцию (`;`).* `[Мой перевод]`

Т.о. вот легитимные варианты:

```
// единственный statement:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)  console.log(i);

// шаблон с блоком, к которому многие слишком привыкли:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    console.log(i);
}

// в самом for(..) третий statement выполняется для каждого цикла:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++, console.log(i));
```

Ваш пример интерпретируется по первому варианту: после `for` исполняется первый statement, который, по-хорошему, должен заканчиваться точкой-с-запятой, но она пропущена, т.к. выражение `!function(i){..}(i)` понимается интерпретатором как единичная инструкция.

Синтакс `!function(i){..}(i)` – просто [на 1 байт короче](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function) более традиционного варианта в скобках: `(function(i){..})(i)` – т.е. определили в первых скобках ф-ю, и тут же её вызвали с параметром из вторых.

Поэтому в приведённом коде выполняется в цикле первое выражение, а второе только раз, после. Это фрагмент кода в довольно нечитаемом виде – вероятно, **после обработки нормального кода минификатором**. Код рабочий, но читать его неприятно.

Answer (score 3):

В случае, когда не указаны фигурные скобки, выполняется только *первое* выражение. В данном примере это функция, она и выполняется в цикле.

Надо *всегда* писать фигурные скобки в цикле `for (;;) {}`. Это считается хорошим тоном и одновременно хорошей темой для споров, но когда они указаны, всегда понятно, что будет выполнено в цикле. Естественно за исключением случая, когда тела у цикла нет, тогда можно ставить `;` вместо фигурных скобок.

Comment: Не знал про выполнение первого выражения, спасибо

Comment: В любом случае рекомендуется использовать блок кода, особенно в пустом цикле. Просто потому, что точку с запятой можно не заметить.

Comment: @AlexKrass  кем конкретно рекомендуется? MDN, вроде, [не рекомендует](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что эти скобки так уж строго рекомендуются. Выражение `!function(i){...}(i)`, конечно, не самое простое для понимания - но прекрасно эти самые фигурные скобки заменяет после привыкания к нему.

Comment: @Sergiks, хороший вопрос. Я отвечу на него так: Дуглас Крокфорд и все те, кто рекомендует пользоваться для проверки синтаксиса своих скриптов JSLint и его правилами. К сожалению, у меня нет точных данных, кто именно эти правила использует.